# lightly feather from image to image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, css

i put upon myself the challenge of doing this:
http://i.minus.com/iV4cpb8tkRjFn.jpg

Using CSS3 or jQuery (or, by now, whatever does the job) in full screen. I've discarded the idea of blurring dynamically, 'cos it would be too heavy. So I've produced 2 images: one normal and one blurred. Then, I tried to feather using some CSS3 magic (basically "feather the center from unblurred image to blurred image") but it didn't cut it. Apparently (at least for now) this trick only work with RGBa.

Does anyone else have an idea of how to do it?

Comment: you mean... how to blur the edges of an image?

Comment: Showing us the final image of what you're after doesn't really tell us what you want to do. Are you trying to render a scene in javascript?! :-D

Comment: Roko: basically. I've seen some javascript stuff that does that but it seems just too heavy for a full screen interface.

Comment: Lee Taylor: oh, sorry. The idea is to radially blur the image, but triying it using javascript made it just too slow. I'll try to put up the tried code to show you guys.